# Extract Email from Headers

Tags: php, imap, imap-open

Can't seem to get my code to work. Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /script.php on line 23. I am looking to retrieve a list of emails addresses:

```
<?php
$mbox = imap_open("{******.com:143/notls}", "******@******.com", "******");

echo "<h1>Email Addresses</h1>\n";
$headers = imap_headers($mbox);

if ($headers == false) {
echo "Call failed<br />\n";
} else {
foreach ($headers as $val) {
preg_match_all('/([^: ]+): (.+?(?:\r\n\s(?:.+?))*)\r\n/m', $headers, $matches);
echo $maches[2] . "<br />\n";
}
}

imap_close($mbox);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/([^: ]+): (.+?(?:\r\n\s(?:.+?))*)\r\n/m', $headers, $matches);
```

should be

```
preg_match_all('/([^: ]+): (.+?(?:\r\n\s(?:.+?))*)\r\n/m', $val, $matches);
```

You were looping through the array, but feeding the entire array into the `preg_match_all` function each loop.

Also, you have a typo:

```
echo $maches[2] . "<br />\n";
```

should be

```
echo $matches[2] . "<br />\n";
```

Comment: A step closer, but all that prints is Array it doesn't give me the value.